# Using PowerShell to import PDF to Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, pdf

I am searching for a way, to import a PDF into Excel using PowerShell.

So far I found one link that seems to have a solution:

http://allthesystems.com/2020/10/read-text-from-a-pdf-with-powershell/

Following the instructions, I had an error regarding the DLL, which I did unlock as read in some comments. Trying a second attempt, I get the following error:

[image]

Is this in combination with [iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader], that it is not able to run the command and if yes, what would I need to do to get it loaded?
Unfortunately, I do not understand, what I am doing wrong and there are no indications or suggestions on the site, that others had a similar issue.

**OR** maybe:
Within Excel, there is the possibility under "Data" to use "Get-Data --> from File --> From PDF"

[image]

Is there a way to use PowerShell to run this step?

Any suggestions and guides welcome, I just try to find a way to have to have PDF files converted and imported into Excel and to automate the process. 
Thank you very much for any help and support,

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike - I believe this would be achievable from Powershell, but the last time I did something like this I went straight to VBA ('Developer' tab in your screenshot), and made a simple button: Detect file, open file, set focus to Adobe Reader, select all, copy, paste to Excel, delimit/format as appropriate, close PDF. VBA would give you more flexibility to easily control your output formatting if Excel is where you want the data to be.

Comment: Dear Steve & K J,
Thank you very much for your feedbacks, I appreciate it. Looks like it is not as easy, as I hoped it would be. Never thought about Macros, haven't used it so far and will look into it. Thank you for sharing your thoughts, Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm solving something similar here and for me it's working on the first try. I'm using Windows 7, PS version 5.1.14409.1018. Try different setup/versions/computer, it should work.